# changing system font size programatically in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I want to know whether it's possible to scale font size in IOS devices programatically. If so can anyoone possibly provide a code to do that?

Comment: have you looked at `UIFont`? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont

Answer (score 0):

`nameLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)` -> Returns an instance of the system font for the specified text style and scaled appropriately for the user's selected content size category.

this can be useful too:

`detailLabel.numberOfLines = 0` -> text don't get stuck in 1 line

`label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true` -> A Boolean value indicating whether the font size should be reduced in order to fit the title string into the label’s bounding rectangle.

`label.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true` -> A Boolean value indicating whether the object automatically updates its font when the device's content size category changes.